# How to get all methods from a file's content (as a String)

Tags: java, class

I have a String, and it contains data as a java class (it means if u copy that String and paste to a file, that file can run and create a java class without any problem).
Now, how can I get all methods in that String? I tried to create a new file, write that String to it, then

> myClass = Class.forName(className);
> Method[] methods = myClass.getMethods();

to get all methods. But it don't work because of before the program ends, that file doesn't exist even though I had closed all writer. So that the first time I run, compiler throws ClassNotFoundException, but the 2nd time, it runs propertly.
[The first time run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77T30.png)   [The 2nd time run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbIqY.png)

Comment: ClassNotFoundException is being thrown at runtime, not by the compiler. Please edit your question to include a minimal example which we can run to reproduce your problem.

Comment: You will have to look at dynamic class loading option. And then tamper your current classpathresourceloader to add new class to the path into current JVM.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that. At runtime, java reads class files, and what you have isn't a class file. It's a source file, a `.java` file.

You need a compiler to compile it, and out of the box you can't reliably assume the VM you run on has one. It's hard to say what got you to the situation that you have a bunch of java code in a big string, but I'd have a long hard look at whatever got you there and find something else.

If you must, most VMs will in fact know about a compiler, and you can get at it via [`ToolCompiler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html). It'll take waaay more code than what you have, though, and note that compiling java code and then opening the resulting class file is quite the security risk unless you fully trust the java code you got.